# Eslint Configuration for Multiple Files / Project

Tags: javascript, eslint

How to configure **eslintrc** for  a project like in this example?

```
user
└── projectA
    ├── index.html
    └── lib
        ├── .eslintrc
        ├── main.js
        └── main_lib.js
```

`html` file *includes* both of the `js` files. How `.eslintrc` is needed to configure to overcome `function is not defined` and `defined but not used` errors properly?

Answer (score 0):

The rules concerned by your question are:

- for `defined but not used` it's the [no-unused-vars](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars) rule
- for `function is not defined`, if you're trying to use a global method declared from an external script, then you can declare it as part of the `global` config in `.eslintrc`, like `"globals": { "yourFunctionName": "readonly" },` to make eslint aware that this function was not declared by you but still it's available from somewhere.